# Can I use the NLA editor to have one Animation "Dampen" Another?

Tags: nla-editor

so i had this idea... and i'm beginning to think it is not actually do-able?

A:

let's say i have an animation, of a limb/arm/tail/tentacle waving.  i later decide it is waving too much.  instead of mucking around in each bone's rotation graphs...  what if i combine it with a second animation, where all the pertinent bones are keyframed for ZERO animation?

i could then blend the two together, in whatever proportion i find aesthetically pleasing or fitting for the job at hand.

after banging my head against the NLA editor (i cannot find any tutorials/explanations on how to work this thing, aside from stringing animations together one after the other.)... i got a test scenario to work.  the bone i keyframed to zero in the second action damped that bone in the first action.  however, ALL THE BONES in the first action had their animations damped.

i believe this has to do with me telling it to blend 50%?  so it just... turned everything down 50%?

B:

let's say i have an action of a dolphin doing a barrel roll.  and i also have one of a dolphin doing a backflip.  i tried using the NLA editor to combine these into a spinner dolphin backflip, but of course, the positioning keyframes of the barrel roll messed with the positioning keyframes of the backflip.

if i create a new action where i ONLY keyframe the, say Y-axis rotation (euler) of the dolphin's root bone, could i then use the NLA editor to blend it with the X and Z rotations of the other action (as well as all the other body parts).

OR... do i need to surgically implant the Y-rotation keyframes from one action to another?

how do you even control the NLA blending?  i tried various iterations of add, subtract, multiply... i finally ended up with my head crushed. (well, the head of my animated character.)

Comment: oh my gosh!! I have a 45 minute tutorial showing how to do this and I didn't upload it this weekend! Please remind me to do it so, tomorrow! Basically: keyframe the arm movement and make it an NLA clip. On the clip properties set the blending mode to ADD. Do not keyframe the COG (center of gravity or main parent of all hierarchy). Just key (record) the movement in the Y or X roll as you want in your bone. All right, the upper top most track will ALWAYS be your keyframe animation that comes from the current ACTION Editor.

Comment: and once you have finished creating an action on the action editor or dopesheet, name the ACTION, and that will be the name of the upper top NLA track. Now, convert it into an NLA clip by pushing it down. You need to understand that everything that is on the NLA dominates the playback. Not the regular timeline, but the NLA TIMELINE. There for you need to create clips and combine them. Keyframe animation can override empty keyframe channels on NLA clips, not on keyframed ones. You need to do all that in blender 2.8

Comment: I am going to sleep. I really would like to help you on this one. As I struggled myself and made it work in the end.